# How to make horizontal tableview like Twitter profile of iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

[image]

I'm not sure it is really made with UITableview though searched few hours on web.

If there is other ways to make it, I would like to know also.

Does anybody have idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you post another image which shows the full view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just looked at the twitter app and the view which I think you are referring to does not scroll from left to right. It just appears to be 3 views/ buttons aligned side by side.

1. You could simply add 3 views side by side with 2 labels in them.
2. Add 3 buttons side by side with custom views in them (if you want to be able to select them).
3. Use a collection view and make a signal reusable cell (if you want to to scroll horizontally).

Comment: I'm just having a idea as 3. 1 and 2 are also useful for me. I'll try 3. Sorry, I don't have reputation to vote +1. Thanks for your prompt answer!